# Are there any extended jQuery Effects available?

Tags: jquery

Are there any jQuery Effects available other than these standard ones?
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects

I am interested both in jQuery and third-party plug-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This easing Plugin integrates with the jQuery annimations.
http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/07/20-demos-showing-advanced-jquery-effects/
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/advanced-jquery-effects/
http://devsnippets.com/article/10-jquery-transition-effects.html

I found something by Googling "jQuery effects".

Comment: Yes, I know about this link, but these are not actual effects. The title is misleading Google search.